# pandas only shows date and drops time when I select data from database

Tags: python, pandas

how are you?

I'm new to pandas and I have faced a problem where I'm using `read_sql`.

```
df = pd.read_sql("select TIME, col_1, col_2 from TABLE", connection)
```

A real database has TIME data which looks like below.

```
         TIME
2017-12-08 00:00:00
2017-12-08 00:00:01
2017-12-08 00:00:02
```

...

Nearly every single second data exist.

Here's a problem. When I read data using pandas, my TIME data looks like

```
2017-12-08
2017-12-08
2017-12-08
```

...

pandas only shows date... where's my time? why is a result different from real data?

Comment: You can use `df.TIME.dtype` to check the datatype.  If `TIME` is not registered as a datetime object, try the [`parse_dates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) argument in `read_sql()`.

Comment: The result of `df.time.dtype` is `dtype('M8[ns]')` which is a datetime as I know. Isn't it?

Comment: Oops, this problem is totally my fault. Data that I read in database and data that I read in pandas is different... omg... Sorry but I learned one which is how I can figure out datetime problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the data manually to see if there is a seconds data? i.e.

```
print(df['TIME'][2].second)
```

If this data exists, then what you see is just the `__str__` representation of `M8[ns]` objects when your print your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to find specific data. I figured it out!